# How to prove two trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry

I want to show that
$${\sin}^2 \alpha + 4{\sin}^4\frac{\alpha}{2} = 4{\sin}^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}$$
and
$${\sin}^2 \alpha + 4{\cos}^4\frac{\alpha}{2} = 4{\cos}^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}$$

They should be true, as Wolfram Alpha says so. However, I want to prove them, and I have no idea how to proceed here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${\sin}^2 \alpha + 4{\sin}^4\frac{\alpha}{2}$$
$$\left(2\sin\frac {\alpha} {2}\cos \frac{\alpha}{2}\right)^2 + 4{\sin}^4\frac{\alpha}{2}$$
$$4\sin^2\frac {\alpha} {2}\cos^2 \frac{\alpha}{2} + 4{\sin}^4\frac{\alpha}{2}$$
$$4\sin^2\frac {\alpha} {2}(\cos^2 \frac{\alpha}{2} + {\sin}^2\frac{\alpha}{2})$$
$$4\sin^2\frac {\alpha} {2}\cdot 1$$
$$4\sin^2\frac {\alpha} {2}$$

same way second part can be prove

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $$\sin^2 \alpha=4\sin^2\frac{\alpha}2\cos^2\frac{\alpha}2$$